# How do I limit individual dictionary inputs in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

Is there a way to put limitations on the integer input of a dictionary? The current way I have it set up checks the whole dictionaries individual inputs after, is there a way I can set it up so it can give more instant feed back. E.g. User inputs an integer value of 6 then an error and prompt appears straight away?

```
def shop_dictionary(shop):
    shop_dict = {}
    for key in range(1, shop + 1):
        shop_name = f"Shop {key}"
        while True:
            try:
                shop_dict[shop_name] = {
                    "Chocolate": int(input(f"{shop_name} Chocolate Amount: ")),
                    "Strawberry": int(input(f"{shop_name} Strawberry Amount: ")),
                    "Vanilla": int(input(f"{shop_name} Vanilla Amount: ")),
                }
                break
            except ValueError:
                print(
                    "Invalid. Please enter an amount between 1 and 5."
                )
        if shop_dict[shop_name]["Chocolate"] < 1 or shop_dict[shop_name]["Chocolate"] > 5:
            print("Invalid number. Please enter a number between 1 and 5.")
            shop_dict[shop_name]["Chocolate"] = int(input(""))
        if shop_dict[shop_name]["Strawberry"] < 1 or shop_dict[shop_name]["Strawberry"] > 5:
            print("Invalid number. Please enter a number between 1 and 5.")
            shop_dict[shop_name]["Strawberry"] = int(input(""))
        if (
            shop_dict[shop_name]["Vanilla"] < 1
            or shop_dict[shop_name]["Vanilla"] > 5
        ):
            print("Invalid number. Please enter a number between 1 and 5.")
            shop_dict[shop_name]["Vanilla"] = int(input(""))
    return shop_dict
```

Preferably I would like to know if this is possible during the input stage, is there something I could write that would do something like the following?

```
                shop_dict[shop_name] = {
                    "Chocolate": integer between range of 1 to 5(input(f"{shop_name} Chocolate Amount: ")),
                    "Strawberry": integer between range of 1 to 5(input(f"{shop_name} Strawberry Amount: ")),
                    "Vanilla": integer between range of 1 to 5(input(f"{shop_name} Vanilla Amount: ")),
                }
```

Thanks. Sorry for the noob question.

Comment: There are a couple of ways this could be done.  1,  Create a function to read user input and don't return unless value input is less than 6.  2) Create a user_dict class which uses the builtin dict class as a super_class and implement the error detection when loading the dictionary.  I think, the first option is the easiest and cleanest approach.

Comment: @itprorh66 how would this look in code? I'm having a hard time picturing it.

Comment: you can start by just putting this in a separate function: `int(input(f"{shop_name} Chocolate Amount: ")` You might have that function raise an error if the value is out of range. Then you wouldn't need most of the remaining code that checks the inputs, since they are already validated.

Comment: @topsail Put the function inside the dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a helper function that doesn't return until user enters correct value.

```
def get_int(prompt, minn, maxx):
    while True:
        try:
            val = int(input(prompt))
            if minn <= val <= maxx:
                return val
        except:
            pass
        print(f"Invalid number. Please enter a number between {minn} and {maxx}.")

def shop_dictionary(shop):
    flavors = ["Chocolate", "Strawberry", "Vanilla"]
    shop_dict = {}
    for key in range(1, shop + 1):
        shop_name = f"Shop {key}"
        shop_dict[shop_name] = {flavor: get_int(f"{shop_name} {flavor} Amount: ",  1, 5) for flavor in flavors}
    return shop_dict
```

If you are not familiar with dictionary comprehension, the line

```
shop_dict[shop_name] = {flavor: get_int(f"{shop_name} {flavor} Amount: ",  1, 5) for flavor in flavors}
```

is the same as

```
shop_dict[shop_name] = {}
for flavor in flavors:
    shop_dict[shop_name][flavor] = get_int(f"{shop_name} {flavor} Amount: ",  1, 5)
```